# How can I properly invoke eslint from a package.json script?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am trying to deploy a function to firebase and there seems to be a problem with ESLint.
I have tried to format it by pressing `Shift` + `Option` + `F`, but that also doesn't seem to work.

When I tried to initialise eslint, it is asking me to create a new package.json file which is already there.

This is the `package.json` file

```
{
    "name": "functions",
    "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
    "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint.js",
        "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
        "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "14"
    },
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^7.6.0",
        "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
        "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

If I use `"eslint ."` instead of `"eslint.js"` in `package.json`, I get following identation errors

```
8:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8   indent
9:8  error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last
```

Comment: It seems that it tries to execute 'eslint.js' as shell command. What is inside this script? Can you try replacing ```"lint" : "eslint.js"``` with ```"lint": "node eslint.js"```. What happens then?

Comment: gives 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' error. I tried using "eslint ." instead of "eslint.js", but it gives me identation and newline errors

Comment: So it says that your code is not formatted according to eslint configuration. If it's not an issue, I think that you can remove `lint` script entry in your package.json

Comment: My original clooud fucntions package.json says ```"lint": "eslint \"src/**/*\"",```. Does that maybe work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. To run eslint, you just want `eslint` in the script, not `eslint.js`.

When eslint runs it's giving you linter output, so fix those issues.

```
8:1  error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8   indent
9:8  error  Newline required at end of file but not found  eol-last
```

This is eslint output indicating you have code that violates the lint rules. Your options are:

1. Fix the indentation and missing newline.
2. Adjust your eslint script to ignore the file with those errors
3. Adjust your lint rules to remove those two rules
4. Stop using eslint.

Comment: I fixed those errors and they are no longer showing it on vscode, but when I try to deploy the functions it gives me the same errors on terminal

Comment: Did.. you save the file?

Comment: When I press cmd + s, it gives me those errors back. I have currently solved the lint problem by removing "predeploy" script from firebase.json file. But I don't think that's the best solution right